# The data in the file automatically deletes after I open the program again

Tags: c++

Okay, I already know that mixing C and C++ is taboo but for the time being this is what I know at the moment because our prof teaches us slightly poor. With that in mind I'm also trying to study by myself reading Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Programming principles and practice using C++". Apparently, our prof told us to create a POS system with these details;

POS(Point-Of-Sale)

```
1.)Allow multiple transaction(Multiple orders)
2.)Payment
3.)Receipt Generation
4.)Update Product Record
5.)View Product list
6.)All transaction should be saved
```

The problem is that whenever I execute that program, put some data in a file and exit the program. The data in the file automatically deletes or reloads whenever I execute the program again. I can't see the problem as is. Please help! :<
PS: you can criticize me because it makes more motivated to write and program codes.

This is the code:

UPDATE:

Okay so I tried using the proper function `fstream` but I still get an error. Maybe its because of the pointers.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
//=============================================================================//
char decide;
int menu,loop = 0,dCheck;
float quan,total = 0.00,sbTotal,scbTotal,scbdTotal,sqpTotal,bsTotal,bsdTotal,ssTotal,sssTotal,fsTotal,mTotal,change,tChange;
double sb = 3.00,scb = 3.50,scbd = 4.50,sqp = 6.50,bs = 8.00,bsd = 9.00,ss = 3.00,sss = 3.25,fs = 2.50,m = 2.00;
//=============================================================================//
struct data{
    /*For the append file*/
    int temp_quan,temp_sbTotal,temp_scbTotal,temp_scbdTotal,temp_sqpTotal,temp_bsTotal,temp_bsdTotal,temp_ssTotal,temp_sssTotal,temp_fsTotal,temp_mTotal;
    /*For the temp file*/
    int t_quan,t_sbTotal,t_scbTotal,t_scbdTotal,t_sqpTotal,t_bsTotal,t_bsdTotal,t_ssTotal,t_sssTotal,t_fsTotal,t_mTotal;
    data *next; 
};
int decideCheck(char a){
    if(decide == 'y' || decide == 'Y'){             
        return 1;   
        }
    else if(decide == 'N' || decide == 'n'){
        return 0;
    }
}
int main(){
    data *a,*b;
    a = new data;
    b = new data;
    fstream *record;
    fstream *tempRecord;
            while(1){
                while(1){/*MAIN MENU*/
                    record.open("Sale Record",ios::app);
                    tempRecord.open("temp Sale Record",ios::out);
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------\n\t\t\tSally's Burgers\n----------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                    cout << "\t\t   ***** Main Menu *****\n================================================================\n";
                    cout << "\t\tItem\t\t\t\tPrice\n\t<1>Sally's Burger\t\t\t$3.00\n\t<2>Sally's CheeseBurger\t\t\t$3.50\n\t<3>Sally's CheeseBurger Deluxe\t\t$4.50\n\t<4>Sally's QuarterPounder\t\t$6.50\n\t<5>BIG Sally\t\t\t\t$8.00\n\t<6>BIG Sally Deluxe\t\t\t$9.50\n\t<7>Sally's Salad\t\t\t$3.00\n\t<8>Sally's Salad with sides\t\t$3.25\n\t<9>Frost Shake\t\t\t\t$2.50\n\t<10>Milkshakes\t\t\t\t$2.00\n\n\t<0>End Order\n";
                    cout << "================================================================\n";
                    cout << "\t\t\t\t\tTotal Amount[ $" << total << " ]";  
                    cout << "\n\t\t   ***** Your Order *****\n\n\t>>Item Number: ";
                    cin >> menu;
                    if(menu == 0){
                        break;
                    }
                    switch(menu){
                        case 1:{
                            cout << "\t>>Item Name <Sally's Burger> |$3.00 each|\n\t>>Quantity: ";
                            cin >> quan;
                            a -> temp_quan = quan;
                            a -> t_quan = quan;
                            sbTotal = quan * sb;
                            a -> temp_sbTotal = sbTotal;
                            a -> t_sbTotal = sbTotal;
                            total = sbTotal + total;
                            record << a -> temp_quan << " Sally's Burger\t\t\t\t$3.00\t$ " << a -> temp_sbTotal;
                            record.close();
                            tempRecord << a -> t_quan << " Sally's Burger\t\t\t\t$3.00\t$ " << a -> t_sbTotal;
                            tempRecord.close();
                            system("cls");
                            break;
                        }
```

Comment: [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) with mode `"w"` destroys the file content if already existing.

Comment: oh dang! didn't saw that. thank you! for pointing that out. cheers.

Comment: Why do you open an directly close the file? In main() `record = fopen("Sale Record","w"); fclose(record);`

Answer (score 1):

As we can see, in your main():

```
int main(){
    data *a;
    a = new data;
    FILE *record;
>   record = fopen("Sale Record","w");
>   fclose(record);
    if(record = fopen("Sale Record","r")){
        fclose(record);
        while(1){
```

`record = fopen("Sale Record","w");` erases the entire file or create a new one if unfound.
It looks to be intentional as the `fclose(record);` suppose it.

`record = fopen("Sale Record","r");` opens the file in read only mode.

If you want to write at the end of the file, you should rather use
`record = fopen("Sale Record","a");`

If you want to do others operations, you can go on [fopen - C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).

Also, I'll rather recommend you to use [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) instead of **stdio.h**, for more details, you can go on [Input/output with files - C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

Answer (score 0):

This just bcs you said that you are mixing C and C++ bcs thats what you only know:

```
#include <iostream> // basic input, output
#include <fstream>  // to "play" with files in C++
using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream fsobj // f(ile)stream object
    fsobj.open("path_and_name_of_file.extension (txt, exe etc.)" , ios::out /*to write to the file*/ | /*each of the "ios" is seperated by |*/ ios::in /*to read*/ | ios::app /* with "ios::out" to write at the end of the file, bcs without it the file is been rewriten from the start*/ )
    fsobj << "Something" << random_variable; // to write, needs : ios::out
    fsobj >> random_variable;                // to read,  needs : ios::in
    fsobj.close();                           // to close the file, when you finish what you want to do with the file better call it, I believe to avoid errors
    return 0;
}
```

A link to help you : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Also, to learn more about C++ I suggest : Sololearn(Free coding tutorial website and mobile app) and "The Cherno"( a YouTube channel, with great tutorials about C++, OpenGL and many other things with a lot of details through better and simple enough explanations)